# spring boot- unable to read yaml properties file application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

I am trying to configure `ldap` server with spring-boot for this i am using `application.yml` file to read ldap url,base,userdn,password etc. from code if i try to read the `application.yml` properties they are always returning null.

below are my files please help me in fixing the issue.

//application.yml
//---------------

```
spring:
      profiles:
        active: TEST 

     ---

    spring:
     profiles: PROD
    logging:
      config: classpath:PROD/log4j2.yml
    ldap:
      url: ldap://pod-url
      base: XXX
      userDn: yyy
      password: password

    ---

    spring:
       profiles: TEST
    logging:
      config: classpath:UAT/log4j2.yml
    ldap:
       url: ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389
       base: dc=example,dc=com
       userDn: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
       password: password
```

//LdapConfig.java
//----------------

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.base.package.*"})
public class LdapConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("ldap.url"));
        contextSource.setBase(env.getProperty("ldap.base"));
        contextSource.setUserDn(env.getProperty("ldap.userDn"));
        contextSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ldap.password"));
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    }


}
```

//from the below file i will be trying use ldapconfig properties

//AuthenticationServiceimpl.java
//------------------------------

```
    public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService {
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AuthenticationServiceImpl.class);


    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
    private LdapContextSource ldapContextSource;

    public boolean authenticateUser(String username, String password) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(LdapConfig.class);
        ldapTemplate = (LdapTemplate) context.getBean(LdapTemplate.class);
        ldapContextSource = (LdapContextSource) context.getBean(LdapContextSource.class);
        DirContext ctx = null;
        try {

            return ldapTemplate.authenticate(ldapContextSource.getBaseLdapPathAsString(), "(uid=" + username + ")",
                    password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("user " + username + " failed to authenticated " + e);
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (ctx != null) {
                org.springframework.security.ldap.LdapUtils.closeContext(ctx);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

//and my main application is

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should work. Try to dump all properties loaded by Spring and check if ldap.* properties are there with expected values. To dump all properties you can use code given here: http://tekbytz.in/tutorials/spring/how-to-display-or-read-all-properties-from-environment-object-in-spring. Hope this will help.

Comment: You should clean your configuration file as indention is important in YAML format. In your example, you've done it pretty badly. Maybe Spring failed to load it correctly. I advise you to use some tools (like https://onlineyamltools.com/prettify-yaml) to do it or install a yaml beautifier in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Use @Value :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.base.package.*"})
public class LdapConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Value("${ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(ldapUrl);
        // ...
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the difference between env.getproperty () and @value notation.

Comment: I am able to read the yaml properties from sprinboot main application if i try to read it from other components i am getting null